# PERL Regular Expression - Return result not including conditional statement

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to regex and I have a scenario where regex will be useful.

My requirement is quite simple, I to want detect if the word NET is present in a string, and extract the digits that follow it without including the word NET or the spaces that follow it.

In my particular case following the word NET are several white space characters, and the number of these can vary as they're used as padding.

My Input string is as follows

```
NET       4.800 g
```

The reg ex I have concocted is as follows

```
(?<=NET)\s*(\d{0,4}\.\d{1,3})
```

This produces a result close to what I'm attempting to do.

It performs a positive look-ahead on the characters NET and then matches as many white space characters that follow. Finally I select up to four digits, a period and up to three more digits.

The problem lies in that I'm grabbing the indeterminate number of padding spaces before the number. All I actually want is the number it self.

I did attempt putting \s* into the lookahead, but this failed. Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Also, when you say that you are "grabbing" the space, that's not actually true, because it is not part of the capture group parentheses. So what do you mean by that? How did you capture the string? Show the code.

Comment: Your regex actually does exactly what you want. It saves just the number, in your case 4.800, in `$1`.

Comment: `echo "NET       4.800 g" | perl -nle 'm/(?<=NET)\s*(\d{0,4}\.\d{1,3})/; print $1'` this outputs `4.800` so it seems to be working

Comment: @Matt I suspect that he is probably using `$&` to capture the string, which would then of course require lookbehind assertion to work, and would include the variable space.

Comment: @TLP, Yes, this was precisely my problem.

Comment: @CapTec You should always include your code when asking questions. Your question makes a good example of that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are using `$&` to capture your string, and not `$1`. The variable `$&` contains the entire matching string, which then includes your spaces, but not your lookbehind assertion. This sounds like your problem description: That you need to exclude a variable amount of spaces, but you get the error about "variable length lookbehind assertions are not supported".

This would be quite an easy question to answer if you had included your code. You should always do that: Always show.

So... I assume you have something like:

```
if (/your_regex/) {
     $match = $&;
}
```

Then you should change it to

```
if (/your_regex/) {
     $match = $1;
}
```

This way, only the string inside the parenthesis will be captured, and `\s*` outside it will be discarded.

With this proper way of matching, which can also be made in a simpler way, you can simplify your regex. Showing a strict and a flexible version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str = "NET       4.800 g";

my ($number) = $str =~ /^NET\s*(\d{0,4}\.\d{0,3})\sg$/;  # strict match
print Dumper $number;         # $VAR1 = '4.800';

my ($simple) = $str =~ /NET\s*([\d.]+)/;                 # flexible match
print Dumper $simple;         # $VAR1 = '4.800';
```

In the strict match, we use anchors at beginning `^` and end `$`. We make sure that the string starts with `NET` and ends with `g`, and account for the exact numbers and spaces we expect to find between.

The flexible match simply looks for `NET` and captures the number that comes after it. This can take place anywhere in the string, and even match partially.

Comment: This is a very good answer, thank you. Your assumption was exactly right in the first instance of using $&. I'll keep it in mind to post my actual code sample next time that I ask a question on S.O. I actually thought it was a problem with the expression it self which is why I didn't.

Comment: @CapTec Yes, I know. The problem is often that users are missing a piece of the puzzle, so they interpret the problem wrong. Which is why code is good, because it is objective.

Comment: @CapTec [`$&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%26), [`$\``](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%60), and [`$'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24') should be [avoided](http://perl-begin.org/tutorials/bad-elements/#non_recommended_regex_vars) as they [can slow down](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) every regex match in the entire program.